# Modal in foreach returning the same data for each modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

i am trying to populate modals with different data, i create the modals buttons using a foreach loop and then i want to apply the relevant data to the right modal.

The problem i have is that the modal is showing the same data for each modal button. How can i make this unique? When its doing its loop its actually placing the correct info but when the page loads its only showing one type of data for every modal.

```
@foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@row["SerialNumber"]</td>
            <td>@row["DtTmGenerated"]</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Error</button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>


@if (Model.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
{
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("cssClass").style.display = 'none';

        }
    </script>
}



<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <h4 class="modal-title justify-content-center">Panda Error information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    var test = Convert.ToString(row["FriendlyError"]);
                    if (test != "No Error" )
                    {
                        <p>@row["FriendlyError"]</p>
                    }



                }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why have you got a <td> tag in modal-body? <td> is only valid if nested in <tr>. Have you tried changing it to <p>?

Comment: I have changed that.. Newbie i am :) But no still doesn't work. I just get the same data for each modal.

Comment: what's you actual end game here, to display a list of FriendlyErrors inside your modal? or are you looking to display a single error and then be able to open the modal for every row in your table?

Comment: Hi glynn. Basically say for instance if my stored proc returned 6 serial numbers, i have 6 modal buttons for each.. If my row[friendlyerror] does not contain "No Error" then show the friendly error else just show "No Error"... But when i click all my modals.. The same message appears for all.. even tho.. there is 100% a friendly message in the table..

Comment: presumably you are seeing all 6 Friendly Errors (or the number of errors that are not "No Error")?. At the moment there is nothing dynamic about what you are doing so you will always see the same result when you open the modal. What you need to do is have a look at using javascript to dynamically update the modal-body when you click on the button in the row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but I had the same problem today and I managed to fix it :D
The problem is the ID of the modal. In each new loop pass your modal is created with the same ID.
In other words: Your values, which come into the modal always change, but because the ID is static, all further modals get the same values as in the first one, because all have the same ID. Try this:

Add this code right after your model (@model ...)

```
@{
int ModalId = 0;
}
```

Then change the ID in the button that opens your modal:

```
data-target="#@ModalId"
```

In the line before you close your foreach, add this

```
@(ModalId++)
```

Change your modal to this and put it into your foreach so that it looks like this:

```
@foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
{
<tr>
    <td>@row["SerialNumber"]</td>
    <td>@row["DtTmGenerated"]</td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@ModalId">View Error</button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="@ModalId" aria-labelledby="@ModalId" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <h4 class="modal-title justify-content-center">Panda Error information</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            var test = Convert.ToString(row["FriendlyError"]);
                            if (test != "No Error")
                            {
                                <p>@row["FriendlyError"]</p>
                            }



                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@(ModalId++)
}
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody></table>
@if (Model.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
{
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("cssClass").style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
}
</body>
</html>
```

In summary: Wherever you had "myModal" as ID, you must replace it with @ModalId

Comment: Edit: Instead of using "ModalId", use the Id of your items

Comment: Otherwise the "@(ModalId++)" will print the value on your view